# Need users to stay connected to the domain even if they temporarily lose Internet connection

Tags: active-directory, vpn, domain, azure

We need to join our users to a domain but they are traveling a lot and often get disconnected from the Internet. I read about "offline domain join" to help them join without contacting a DC, but is it possible for them to have uninterrupted work even after loosing connection after joining the domain?

The DC is a VM in Azure cloud and they need VPN access to join the domain.

Comment: Are you talking about *new* users/PCs joining a domain, or *current* users/PCs accessing a domain?

Comment: by work you mean what ? as some solution exist, workfolder, etc.., but depend what your user do

Comment: @GregL We are still planning to join the client PC's to domain. But I need to know once they are joined and then if they lose connection will they still be able to authenticate. We are using SSO for a lot of applications.

Comment: Once a PC is joined to the domain and a user logs on to it once while connected to the network, and with domain credentials, they'll be cached on the machine. This allows them to logon again later even if they're offline. Not sure about the rest of your SSO applications, it would depend on how they work.

Answer (score 0):

**[Offline Domain Join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/offline-domain-join-djoin-step-by-step(v=ws.10).aspx)** is the technology that allows computers to join domain without contacting domain controller, when they don't have connectivity to corporate network.

Once they are joined to a domain they should have no problem working **(accessing locally stored files, logging in and logging out)** on their computer as long as work does not need corporate network.

Hence, offline domain join will not help you authenticate SSO if they need corporate network or are hosted internally.